# iOS how to start image off screen and animate it onto the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-animations

I am trying to slide an image from off the screen onto the screen from the left and stopping at the center point in the view.  I would like to keep it contrained at the y position if possible (IE image is set in story board).

I am reading this tutorial, but it is in swift and I cannot make the same assignments in objective-c.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/95910/uiview-animation-swift-tutorial

It says to set the view off the screen (in swift):

```
heading.center.x  -= view.bounds.width
```

Then animate (in swift):

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
    self.heading.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
})
```

However I cannot manipulate center.x in objective c like they are doing in swift.

I have tried adjusting the initial position of the image in viewWillAppear by changing the bounds with no luck.

EDIT:

Here is what I am trying to get it positioned off the screen:

```
self.heading.center = CGPointMake(-200, self.heading.center.y);
```

No matter how negative I set the x position the view will still appears on the screen.  Actually no matter what I set x position to the view does not move in the x direction at all.  I have also tried to set the frame

Answer (score 1):

The *x* coordinate of the view's center is not directly assignable in Objective-C. Instead, try setting the center point as whole. In your example, this could look something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    CGFloat newCenterX = self.heading.center.x + self.view.bounds.size.width;
    self.heading.center = CGPointMake(newCenterX, self.heading.center.y);
}];
```

Comment: Doesn't explain how to get it initially off the screen. See my edit.

Comment: @lostintranslation So you can't influence the position of the view programatically at all? Did you perchance enable [Auto Layout](http://i.imgur.com/sNQ99rK.png) for its superview, in the Storyboard or otherwise? If that's the case, any Auto Layout constraints applying to your view will prevent you from manipulating its frame yourself.

Comment: Well that has to be it. Pretty sure I have auto layout on and constraints. Although that brings up all kinds of other questions on how to align and constrain views across different devices and landscape/portrait. So no way to use animations and have constraints? BTW thanks for the help, truly appreciated.

Comment: Also animation does move the view. Not sure if that matters. But yeah initially setting the view to off screen does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation:

```
      [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:5
                               delay:0
                               options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear
                               animations:^{

                               view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(550, -40);
                               }];
```